# No matching distribution found for swig

Tags: swig

(venv) C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\My Projects\tf-openpose>pip install swig
Collecting swig

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement swig (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for swig

(venv) C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\My Projects\tf-openpose>

What's wrong here?

Comment: em.. interesting questions.

Answer (score 1):

SWIG isn't a Python package, but a code generator that can be used to generate C/C++ extension code for multiple languages, including Python.  Download it from http://www.swig.org/.